# How to send message from bot to user at a fixed time or at intervals through python telegram bot library?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to send messages to bot daily without trigger from user side (eg commandhadler) from second conversation onwards.

I have build a basic menu for bot to interact with user

[image]

But i am also trying to send messages daily through job_queue

I have refered codes which are using commandhandlers

```
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("set", set_timer,
                              pass_args=True,
                              pass_job_queue=True,
                              pass_chat_data=True))
```

This is being set after user types /set .
But I am trying to find a way to automatically send messages every 30 seconds or set a fixed time for message to be sent daily 
My code

```
from telegram.ext import Updater,CommandHandler 
from telegram.ext import  MessageHandler,Filters,InlineQueryHandler
import logging
import telegram

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger()

def start(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text("Hello , Thanks for choosing us!!")

def callback_minute(context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):
    chat_id = ?
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, 
                             text='Hi User, Add Fund to your account to start trading')


def main():
    updater = Updater(token,use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    j = updater.job_queue
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start",start))
    job_minute = j.run_repeating(callback_minute, interval=10, first=0)

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()
```

How to get chat_id?
If i am using

```
def callback_minute(update, context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: callback_minute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
```

Comment: You cannot get `chat_id` in this way. `chat_id` can be obtained only from `update` object, and `update` object will be fetched only when user sends a message to Bot. First, move the job_queue lines to a separate function. Then this function should be called using any Handlers.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code, as i have tried to pus h it to start ,but not working

Comment: How do you want to start this job of sending messages? What should be the triggering point for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `context.job_queue.run_repeating()` to repeat the job continuously after specific time interval.

If you want the job to execute once everyday, you can use `context.job_queue.run_daily()` and specify the time.

These are `python-telegram-bot` docs links for both of the cases:
[job_queue.run_repeating()](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_repeating), [job_queue.run_daily()](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_daily)

These docs have very good information which will help your query.

Answer (score 4):

It is reworked below so that run_repeating() is called from the `/start` command (as suggested by Gagan T K in the comments). In this example `first=30` so it will start after 30 seconds.

There is a good example of using the job queue in this way at the bottom of [the wiki documentation for JobQueue](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) on GitHub.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater,CommandHandler 
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler,Filters,InlineQueryHandler
import logging
import telegram

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger()

bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)

def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
                     text="Hello , Thanks for choosing us!!")

    context.job_queue.run_repeating(callback_minute, interval=10, first=30,
                                    context=update.message.chat_id)

def callback_minute(context):
    chat_id=context.job.context
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, 
                             text="Hi User, Add Fund to your account to start trading")

def main():
    updater = Updater(token,use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start",start, pass_job_queue=True))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: After restarting the bot user will have to press /start again? No way to make this work after bot restarted? Only if store the chat_id in a database or a dictionary?